# Segue not working with iOS6

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, segue

excuse me if my question may sound stupid to some of you. I am relatively new to iOS Development but I have to port an app for iOS6. The app works perfectly on iOS 5 and XCode 4.3.2 but I am having a weird bug with Xcode 4.5 on the iPhone 6.0 simulator.
After the initial screen is loaded I can hit any button I want, and I get the error:

```
 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'register'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.`
```

The prepareForSegue method of the StartScreenViewController looks like this

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"register"] || [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"forgotPassword"]) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[segue destinationViewController]];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = navController;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint shows me that the method is still called corectly, but after the prepareForSegue is finished, the app crashes with the forementioned error. Could anybody point me into the right direction?

Thank you very much
Martin

Answer (score 5):

Because you're using a `push segue`  **Cocoa is looking for an ancestral navigation controller in the hierarchy** of *StartScreenViewController*.

- If it finds one, it will use it to automatically push a new view controller onto that navigation controller's stack.
- **Since it's not finding one, your app is crashing.**

`prepareForSegue`: exists for you to *configure* a VC that's about to get automatically displayed by iOS. It isn't your responsibility to *display* the VC, which is what you seem to be doing when you set window.rootViewController.

You may want to read through these docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5):

You can say "the app was working perfectly", but the fact is that the code you cite was always very wrong, so it seem that this wrongness is now being exposed. You should never change the window's root view controller in the middle of the app; you should set it once at launch and never again. And, as Joshua has rightly said, preparing for a segue is not a time for you to mess with the view controller structure, which the segue itself about to mess with.

You've got a basket case on your hands. It might be a good idea for you to stop and understand iOS and view controllers (and storyboards) before you take another step, since you may end up ripping up the entire architecture of this app in order to get it right. Here's some help:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. App works well on ios6 device, when downloaded form app store, but the same code doesn't work either on device or simulator. Very strange problem.

My app structure is as follows:

**NavigationController** -> **UIViewController** (has PageControl, hold multiple pages, horizontally scrollable) -> **UITableViewController** (represents one list of news for one category), and when user clicks on a single news, gets **DetailsViewController** (instance of UIViewController).

This is the code from prepareForSegue:

```
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowTelegrafDetails"]){
    TelegrafDetailsViewController *details = (TelegrafDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];     

    if([self isItPad])
        details.linkFromTableView = [[otherNews objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row] link];
    else
        details.linkFromTableView = [[[myViewController.itemMatrix objectAtIndex:[self calculateCurrentPage]] objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row] link];

    NSLog(@"%@",segue.sourceViewController);
    NSLog(@"%@",segue.destinationViewController);

    [self.myViewController.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
    }
```

Seems that source view controller is set as it is supposed to, i use storyboards and NavigationController is automatically set. I don't know if i have to set RootViewController somewhere explicitly, but it could be tricky to set it in AppDelegate, because i have two more view hierarchies between delegate and a class that should be root (UITableViewController).

If anyone knows something more about it i am eternally grateful, otherwise i could use some directions. I've read apple's documentation regarding this topic, but i cannot fully understand it when it comes to this complex situations.

Also, if i find any solution, i will gladly post it here like a boss. :D

Thanx in advance.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to fix this problem. Just removed segues, and put the code from **prepareForSegue** into **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, with appropriate corrections. It is not an ideal solution, but fixes the problem. Although, i have in plan to support 4.3+ devices, and storyboards are not an option in that case.

Also, i've double checked code, found out that RootViewController is correctly created and displayed, NavigationController works well, and i still cannot understand why segues wont work.

Cheers.